# How to separate icons inside of the tag <md-list-item>?

Tags: css, material-design, angular-material

My question is why this elements are not separate as is suppose to be with some margin from left and right. And what if I want to see this elements in a mobile, it will be a mess. So what I missing here in order to separate the elements correctly and don't get mix together .?

Note:
Hey here is the following code that I have and after the code click on the link to see image.

```
<md-list-item layout="row">
          <img  ng-src="assets/img/iconUser.png" class="md-avatar" alt="none"/>
          <p flex ng-bind="c.username"></p>
          <p flex ng-bind="c.email"></p>

          <md-button flex class="md-secondary md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" aria-label="Add Contact">
           <md-icon class="md-hue-1" md-svg-icon="assets/img/plus1.svg"  
           aria-label="Add Contact">
           </md-icon>
          </md-button>

          <md-button flex class="md-secondary md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" aria-label="Send Email">
           <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/img/message.svg"  
           aria-label="Send Email" 
           class="md-secondary" >
           </md-icon>
          </md-button>

        </md-list-item>
```

[this is the picture of the  md-list-item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaoX5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you have `class="md-secondary"` on the second `md-icon`. If you remove it (or replace it with `class="md-hue-1"` as the other  `md-icon`) it works fine - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/AXGzkW?editors=1000)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <img  ng-src="assets/img/iconUser.png" class="md-avatar" alt="none"/>
    <p flex>John</p>
    <p flex>john.smith@gmail.com</p>

    <md-button class="md-secondary md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" aria-label="Add Contact">
      <md-icon class="md-hue-1"  md-svg-src="img/icons/cake.svg" aria-label="Add Contact"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="md-secondary md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" aria-label="Send Email">
      <md-icon class="md-hue-1" md-svg-src="img/icons/android.svg" aria-label="Send Email"></md-icon>
    </md-button>

  </md-list-item>
</div>
```